# @Controller не возвращает HTML - страницу, после перехода с H2 database на mysql server

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping("/record_by_id/{id}")
public String index(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("TB",this.telephoneBookService.findById(id));
    return "index";
}
```

В логе пишет:

```
2017-10-29 11:54:28.340  WARN 3292 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "index"
```

раньше работало с использованием h2 database, когда поменял на mysql server, перестало, но все остальное работает, например с аннотацией @ResponceBody в браузере все выводит норм, но если только хочу вернуть html страницу - варн.

Comment: Я думаю, смена базы тут не при чем

Comment: Что тогда не так?

Comment: У вас что-то не то с ViewResolver. Текст ошибки наводит на мысль, что он пытается строку "index", которую возвращает метод `index`.  передать этому же методу.